# Putting results of function into a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, global

I'd like to put function results into a dictionary (columns_categories_dict) within another function (cert_register_excel_sheet_populator())  like below:

```
def value(category, row):
    return spreadsheet_defaultdict[str(category)][row - 1].strip()

def cert_register_excel_sheet_populator():
    columns_categories_dict = {
                        'A':value("Policy Number", row),
                        'C':" ".join(value("Policyholder", row).split(", ")[::-1]),
                        'D':value("Vehicle Reg. Number", row),
                        'E':custom_strftime('{S} %B, %Y', renewal_date) + ' - ' + custom_strftime('{S} %B, %Y', expiry_date),
                        'F':datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
                        }
```

However I get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Millar\Desktop\Python Sandbox\Prem Calc to Motor Cert Populator\Sagicor Tickertapes, Motor Certs.py", line 387, in <module>
    cert_register_excel_sheet_populator()
  File "C:\Users\Millar\Desktop\Python Sandbox\Prem Calc to Motor Cert Populator\Sagicor Tickertapes, Motor Certs.py", line 320, in cert_register_excel_sheet_populator
   'A':value("Policy Number", row),
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'value' referenced before assignment
```

I tried to make value a global  but then that turns my original value function into a string. I could potentially find a work around and use a loop to populate my dictionary but is there a more elegant solution to this?

Update: I created the following simple code to demonstate my problem. The code works.

```
def first_function():
    return print("I am working")

def second_function():
    columns_categories_dict = {
                        'A':first_function(),
                        'B':'wow',
                        'C':print("third value")
                        }
second_function()
```

And the print out:

```
========= RESTART: Desktop/function conflict test.py =========
I am working
third value
```

I searched my code to see if I used value as a variable and I haven't....

Comment: I don't see where you are assigning a value to `row`.

Comment: in theory your script seems fine if we exclude what @Matt correctly pointed out.

Comment: The problem is why Python thinks `value` is a variable... Or is that a typo? If I were the Python interpreter, I'd say `local variable 'row' referenced...`

Comment: Sorry the value for row is fed in through a loop usually. I'm adding additional functionality to them. I have isolated these functions from my code and the problem is how to get function results into a dictionary. Python thinks value is a variable when its actually a function......

Comment: then you probably have the `cert_register_excel_sheet_populator()` function higher up the code than `value()`

Comment: cert_register_excel_sheet_populator() is lower in the code than value()

Comment: Show us the errors you get (and don't understand) when running *this* code.  Reducing the problem size is admirable, but you have cut it down so far that you have eliminated the problem.

Comment: it cannot be. try a minimal example with two functions and you will see. forget your complicated code for a moment. Look at that: https://repl.it/CocC/0

Comment: Ok Ev. I will try this

Comment: Hey guys, I couldn't find where I went wrong, so I just defined the same function with a different name and it works. Thanks for the help!